# Adobe Flash. Mouseover animation endless loop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, button, adobe

I'm having some problems while making a button for a site. I created a button and an animation, then imported that animation as an .swf to the button file. I used the following code(with btn being the button and mc the movie clip):

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,btnF);
function btnF(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    mc.play();
}
```

As you can imagine, when the mouse is over the button, the animation plays, but it doesn't stop... Any Solutions?

Details: Using Actionscript 3.0
And yes, i made the movie clip with a **stop()** code at the end... so I don't see why it loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler to do it this way: create a button, on default state have the graphic for the button. On the over state use a movieclip with your animation. That should work without any code

Comment: "I created a button and an animation"
Looks like the button and the animation are two different objects.

Comment: I mean.. i created a button and another animation.... but it's right, instead of importing that movie clip i should have done it "inside" the button animation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the MOUSE_OVER event will always fire if the mouse is over that "btn" display object. So the stop() code works at the end, but the play overwrites that command.

Here is a possible solution:

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, btnF);
function btnF(e:MouseEvent):void{
{
     if(mc.currentFrame == 1)
     {
          mc.play();
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//i called the instance of the button : buthead and the instance of the movie clip : head_mc
//on the first frame of the movie clip, i've put a stop function

buthead.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    head_mc.play();
});
```

Comment: Could you add more details to your answer?